# Как более корректно запретить нажатия?

Tags: веб-программирование

такой вопрос. У меня есть функционал на сайте где до того как пользователь не введет адрес ему запрещено нажимать на кнопку заказать. Я сделал через простую проверку на добавления класса для кнопки к примеру disabled. И все бы хорошо однако если к примеру найдется человек знающий базовые элементы инспектора он может просто удалить класс и спокойно нажмет на кнопку. Тот же случай с суммой. Там лучше всего сделать запрет?
Стек MERN

Comment: А зачем он это будет делать?

Comment: @AlexeyTen: затем, что даже в вопросе неясно какой адрес вводить - проживания или электронный :)

Comment: Я адрес для примера указал. Вопрос же совсем в другом

Comment: Нормальному клиенту нет смысла обходить (разумные) ограничения. Ему нет смысла отправлять заказ без адреса/даты доставки и т.п.  А «хакер» всегда может отправить запрос прямо из консоли и любая защита тут бессильна. Так что мне всё ещё непонятно от чего и зачем вы хотите защититься.

Comment: Назначайте событие на кнопку только после валидации в таком случае. А так против лома нет приёма

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея примерно такая.

Назначайте событие на кнопку только после валидации в таком случае.

```js
let address = document.getElementById("address");
let order = document.getElementById("order");

address.addEventListener("change", ()=>{ 
  if (!address.value) { // добавьте свою валидацию
    order.removeEventListener("click", makeOrder);
    order.disabled = true;
  } else { 
    order.addEventListener("click", makeOrder);
    order.disabled = false;
 }
});

order.disabled = true;

function makeOrder(){
  console.log("Заказать");
}
```

```html
<input id="address" type="text">
<button id="order" >Заказать</button>
```